# Changing standard output in middle of program not printing previous printf to console

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

I just learned about file descriptors and I was trying some code to understand the way it works. When writing the following program I was expecting that the first printf should be written to the console, then since I close the standard output and open a new file, I expected it to return the smallest file descriptor which is 1 (since it is available because I closed it previously). Then I was expecting the second printf to write to the file file.txt.

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
        printf("before close");
        close(1);
        int x1 = open("./file.txt", O_RDWR);
        printf("after close, the file descriptor is %d\n", x1);
}
```

However, when I execute this, nothing is printed to the console but everything is printed to the file.txt, i.e.

**file.txt**

```
before closeafter close, the file descriptor is 1
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a *buffering* issue.

Output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is *buffered*. When `stdout` is connected to an interactive terminal then it's *line buffered*, which means the output is flushed (actually written) on newline.

So if you want the first output to be written to the console, add a newline to the output:

```
printf("before close\n");
```

As an alternative you could use `fflush(stdout)` to explicitly flush the buffer. But note that since you don't print a newline, the output could seem to run into the shell prompt. Or the shell could print a special character to indicate the lack of newline, which could sometimes be confusing.

---

What is happening with your current code is that the output from the first `printf` call stay in the buffer, and will be written when the second call leads to a flush of the buffer. By then the output will have been "redirected" to the file.

---

Note that the buffering is set before the `main` function is called. Just because you change the destination for `stdout` by closing and reopening the file descriptor doesn't mean the buffering will change. Your program will still be line buffered after the `close` and `open` calls.

If you want to change the buffering of `stdout` you need to use the [`setvbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf) function.